# ¿Cómo leer una entrada "echo" de bash en C?

Tags: c

Tengo un programa en C que consiste en invertir las líneas de uno o varios ficheros y que me funciona correctamente. Pero ahora quiero también poder invertir por entrada estándar. Y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Por ejemplo, mi programa se llama `delreves` y si ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
./delreves meses.txt
```

Con el fichero meses.txt teniendo un contenido como el siguiente:

```
enero
febrero
marzo
```

entonces obtengo la siguiente respuesta:

```
orene
orerbef
ozram
```

---

Ahora mi problema es que lo quiero cambiar para que si lo llamo así:

```
echo "abcder" | delreves
```

El resultado sea:

```
redcba
```

No sé cómo hacer para que mi programa sepa detectar que se le ha metido algo por entrada *stdin* y que sepa a su vez que no se trata de un fichero y cómo invertirlo.

Comment: esto huele a tarea.. que llevas?

Comment: Si es de la universidad. Pero lo que es el 90% ya lo tengo hecho, solo me falta esto y he probado diferentes metodos de hacerlo, pero ninguno me lleva a cabo a realizar bien la entrada con comando echo. Lo importante es lo que he puesto al final de la pregunta.

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres es comprobar si el fichero existe, ¿no? Si el fichero existe, se invierte su contenido; y si no, es una cadena y se invierte directamente la cadena

Comment: Por el ejemplo, entiendo que necesitás hacer un 'pipe' (una tubería) entre dos procesos. Podrías empezar por aquí [http://es.tldp.org/Universitarios/seminario-1.html].

Answer (score 1):

Puedes diferenciar los casos a base de el argc.En el primer caso, argc va a ser igual a 2. En el segundo argc va a ser 1. Entonces podrias hacer algo similar a esto:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        // Lees desde stdin y lo inviertes
    } else if (argc == 2) {
        // Abres el archivo y lo inviertes;
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No se si me ha quedado claro tu pregunta.

**NO** puedes distinguir entre que se le pase un archivo o una entrada de texto; desde el punto de vista de tu programa, es lo mismo `echo XXX | delreves` que `cat archivo.txt | delreves`.

Si lo quieres es saber si tiene que *revertir* un archivo o leer desde `stdin`, no tienes mas que comprobar los argumentos que se le pasan. Si no se le pasa ninguno, es que tiene que leer desde `stdin`. Para eso, se usa `argc`, uno de los argumentos de main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  while( argc-- )
    printf( "%s ", argv[argc] );

  return 0;
}
```

Las funciones son las mismas que estás usando, pero en lugar de abrir tu el archivo, usas el `FILE *stdin`, que está definido igualmente en `<stdio.h>`.